# Phpunit, why is this a dead code?

Tags: phpunit

I'm using PHPUnit (4.1.3) and it calls something as dead code:

[image]

it really annoys me. Its OK that codes after `return` are dead, but calling a closing bracket as dead code is just overkill

Comment: With the uncoloured lines in there, it makes me wonder if it has got its line numbers wrong. Is it perhaps expecting 1TBS indentation?

Comment: This is afaik a known bug in phpunit/xdebug. I'm afraid you will have to live with it - like I do :)

Comment: Please show the whole method

Answer (score 10, accepted):

XDebug parsing issue, so the closing brace is not executed after the return statement since the code leaves that function and does not actually execute the closing brace.  This is a known issue in the XDebug/PHP/PHPUnit parsing/executing space.

Comment: pity :( in the meantime I found a 6 year old topic about that. It has problem with comments too

Comment: I know. It seems that the combination of tools has the issue.  It would be nice if either PHPUnit or XDebug could unflag this as dead code, and simply work around the bug.  I believe it might be something PHPUnit could do, by simply ignoring the closing brace line, but not sure on the history of the issue and why neither tool has addressed it, since it would be out there for a number of us to suffer through.  Maybe we can open a ticket on both tools and get one of them not to report the dead code line?

Comment: its even more complicated. Ive just realized that Phpunit say its 100% covered, even tough that 2 "dead" line

Comment: That may be a fix in PHPUnit to ignore the closing brace to say it is covered.